# Loop through some results to find a path and push it to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, foreach, reduce

I need to create a loop to search into some results to find a path and push it into an array but the way I wrote the loop, it searches only the first position, the [0].

How do I loop all of results positions in order to extract the path from all of them?

For better understanding, please check the image and the code below:
[image: structure]

The code so far looks like:

```
let results = data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results;

//loop on each results
results[0].Cells.results.forEach(el => {
  let filePath = el.value;
  let fileName = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, filePath.length);

  // push to array
 pathResults.push(fileName);
});
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const pathList = data
  .d.query
  .PrimaryQueryResult
  .RelevantResults
  .Table.Rows
  .results
  .reduce((list, { Cells }) => {

    const cellPathItem = Cells
      .results.find(({ Key }) => Key === 'Path');

    if (cellPathItem) {
      list.push(
        cellPathItem.Value.substring(
          cellPathItem.Value.lastIndexOf('/')
        )
      );
    }
    return list;

  }, []);
```

> *"Thanks for your sophisticated solution! Could you please show me an approach based more on my existing code?"*

```
const pathList = [];

data.d.query
  .PrimaryQueryResult
  .RelevantResults
  .Table.Rows
  .results
  .forEach(rowItem => {

    const cellPathItem = rowItem.Cells
      .results.find(cellItem => cellItem.Key === 'Path');

    if (cellPathItem) {
      pathList.push(
        cellPathItem.Value.substring(
          cellPathItem.Value.lastIndexOf('/')
        )
      );
    }
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your sophisticated solution! Could you please show me an approach based more on my existing code?

Comment: There is nothing sophisticated with using `reduce`. In terms of iteration and finding it is as straightforward as can be. A `forEach` based approach would look exactly the same just with pushing into an array which had to be declared before.

Comment: @onweb ... updated ... check yourself ... the differences are not that significant.